# Filter spread.js spreadsheet using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wijmo

I am following along with the examples for spread.js and can't seem to figure out how to implement the filter functionality using angular.js. The documentation is kind of thin:

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadHClientUG/webframe.html#angular.html
http://wijmo.com/demo/spreadjs/samples/ExplorerSample/?widget=Filter&sample=Filter

I found that a simple angular filter on the datascource attribute for the  directive worked however if creates an error in the console "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

**Markup**

```
                </row>                
            </rows>
        </sheet>
    </sheets>
</wij-spread>
<input ng-model="searchText" />
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('SpreadApp', ['wijspread']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.Sheets = [{ "sheetName": "Sheet1" },{ "sheetName": "Sheet2" }];
    $scope.data = [{"id":"hello"},{"id":"Good bye"}];
});
```

Comment: It would help if you could throw up a fiddle or plnkr showing what you've done already.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it? It helps to keep SO clean.